# Ranking vs Rank which one is correct in the sentence

Tags: word-choice

Please help which one is grammatically correct... There is no context just wondering...

1) I want to compare your course rank versus others rank.

2) I want to compare your course rank versus others ranking.

3) I want to compare your course ranking versus others ranking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both "rank" or "ranking" may be correct in particular contexts. They might mean rather different things, but both can function as nouns, so both fit the grammar.

We would normally "compare A *with* B" or "compare A *against* B, not "compare A versus B", and there is probably no need to repeat the word "rank"

> I want to compare your course ranking with others'.
>
> I want to compare your course ranking against others.